# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

hice el comando

```
composer require laravel/ui -dev 
php artisan ui vue -auth
```

y intengo registrarme y me salta el siguiente error

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Ya configuraste el archivo .env con tus credenciales de acceso?, pues los comandos que muestras no tienen nada que ver con el error generado

Comment: Si puse en .env DB_* los configuré

Comment: Te recomiendo revisarlo pues el error parece indicar que te falta la contraseña

Comment: adjunto una foto de mi archivo

Comment: nada, sigue igual :S

Comment: lo estoy corriendo por vagrant, sabes si hay algun comando para reiniciar la maquina?

Comment: ¿Puedes ingresar desde la terminal de `mysql` con esas credenciales sin ningún problema?

Comment: Si, puedo hacerlo sin problemas

Comment: reinicio la maquina y aun asi me sigue dando el problema

Comment: Probablemente sea problema de que no se está leyendo el archivo supongo `.env` o quizá se sobreescribe la configuración, ¿puedes agregar más información por favor? Pienso eso porque en tu archivo tienes como host `127.0.0.1` que técnicamente es `'root'@'127.0.0.1'` pero en el error aparece `'root'@'localhost'`, que no debería existir ningún problema pues seguramente root se puede conectar desde ambos hosts, que técnicamente son el mismo, pero puede indicar que no se está leyendo bien la configuración.

Comment: que información pongo más? no sé como puedo aportar, no se me ocurre nada mas que poner :S Lo unico que he hecho crear un proyecto hacer los comandos que dije en el main y crear auth, e intentar registrarme y al intento registrarme me salta el error

Comment: en el archivo host tengo lo siguiente  127.0.0.1 localhost

Comment: ¿Podrías ejecutar el mismo comando con mayor verbosidad para depurar por favor? agrega `-vvv` al comando

Comment: que comando de los dos ? * composer require laravel/ui -dev 
* php artisan ui vue -auth

Comment: ya tengo la respuesta

Comment: Perdón, el comando que utilizas para conectarte, en el que ocurre el error, como lo mencionó @BetaM, los comandos que publicaste no tienen que ver con el error que te sale. También es posible que no sea -vvv sino --verbose o algo así, depende del comando que uses, o inclusive puede no tener esa opción

Comment: Probaste dejando la contraseña vacía? Por lo que veo es error de MySQL, no de laravel.

Answer (score 1):

```
php artisan route:cache 
php artisan route:clear 
php artisan config:cache 
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco tu respuesta. Mira cómo responder: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

A mi también me pasaba lo mismo lo primero que hice fue limpiar la caché así:

- php artisan config:cache
- php artisan config:clear
- php artisan cache:clear

Después de eso lo que hice fue checar mi .env donde checara que estos campos coincidieran con el nombre de la database:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ldaw
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Si no ves ninguna configuración de base de datos en el archivo .env, tal vez necesitas agregar información de conexión para tu usuario raíz en ese archivo.
El error que te aparece no es de Laravel, creo que es de MySQL. Y usualmente en el campo de la contraseña no se escribe nada, borra lo que escribiste ahí, vuelve a limpiar la caché y reinicia el servidor.